# Why does the transparent glass material not allow the emission to pass through?

Tags: modeling, lighting

I have light bulb. There is filament inside and it have emission 60000.
MATERIAL of filament:
[image: filamnet]

MATERIAL of bulb:
[image: materials]

PROBLEM:
[image: light is not passing through]

BUT if i turn off bulb i have this:
[image: it's blinding without bulb))]

Comment: Hello, is the bulb a solidifed object ? Have you changed the maximum transmission bounces in the render properties ? How many samples do you render at ? 60 000 emission strength is a LOT especially at this scale (assuming you modelled the object at scale)

Answer (score 0):

Cycles doesn't handle this kind of direct lighting terribly well. The only way I know of to rectify this is to reduce the Alpha value of the glass material to something like 0.5.

Comment: I know this way, but thought this is not correct. thank you for answer

Comment: You’re welcome. The only other way i can think to do this is to make the emission material a dummy and add an actual light (i.e. Shift A : Light) which is just slightly bigger than the diameter of the bulb glass.

Comment: way with using fake emission and adding light point leads to strange result. 
screen: https://ibb.co/YWDLD7m